# How to do a line plot with vertical lines indicating changes in group

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a data set with the following structure:

[image]

Group2 are the individual identifiers and Group1 are larger groups identifiers to which each individual belong to.
I need to plot the Value column on the y-axis in the order in which they appear in the Group2 column, but letting the x-axis labels to be from the Group1 column and not from Group2. Then I need to add  vertical lines for each change of value of Group1, so that I can identify which part of the plot belongs to group A, group B and so on, similar to this example (ignore the yellow and purple lines, I just need a single line):
[image]

The blue vertical line represents when all the individuals from group A have been plotted, and now we start plotting the individuals from group B and so on.
Any ideas on how do achieve this?

```
import pandas as pd

a = {'Group1':['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B','C', 'C', 'C'], 'Group2': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'B1', 'B2', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
    'Value':[0.06, 0.12, 0.11, 0.04, 0.09, 0.2, 0.1, 0.08, 0.2]}

df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df.set_index(['Group1', 'Group2'], inplace=True)
```

Comment: Can you give more details on how are you seeking to generate the output plot, looking at the input data, I fail to see how you get those line plots and what they mean

Comment: @SurajShourie I have edited the question, hopefully is more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use matplotlib for this, vertical lines can be added using `plt.axvline` and you'll need to customize your `xticks`:

```
# init
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = {'Group1':['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B','C', 'C', 'C'], 'Group2': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'B1', 'B2', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
    'Value':[0.06, 0.12, 0.11, 0.04, 0.09, 0.2, 0.1, 0.08, 0.2]}

df = pd.DataFrame(a)

# plot
cumsum = df.groupby('Group1')['Value'].count().cumsum()
a =  [0] + cumsum.to_list()
a = [0.5*(a[i] + a[i+1]) for i in range(len(a)-1)]
plt.plot(range(len(df)), df['Value'])

# update x ticks
plt.xticks(a, cumsum.index)

# add vertical lines
for x in cumsum - 0.5:
  plt.axvline(x=x, color='red')
```

Output:

[image]